# Scheduled emails not working

Tags: civimail, civievent, scheduled-reminders

I have set up scheduled reminder emails for events, but they do not seem to go out. I tested it by signing up for an event myself and did not receive a reminder email. Anyone got any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First of all you need check you mail configuration is working properly or not.

Comment: See also: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/creating-civimail-cron-job-in-cpanel

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled the **Send Scheduled Reminders** scheduled job? You can check by going to *Administer > System Settings > Scheduled Jobs*. Scroll down to **Send Scheduled Reminders** and ensure that the *Enabled?* box is set to *Yes*.

You'll also need to ensure that you have a cron job enabled for your Civi installation.

Comment: refer to this link on managing scheduled jobs
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem - it was due to the developers setting the cron job to only run once per day at midnight (not very useful for timely responses!)