# Cron job with shared hosting CPanel

Tags: cron-job, cron

I've tried different ways to setup cron jobs.

When using that cron job, the file is not able to read the parameters (like key, etc.)

> /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.site.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXXX&pass=XXXX&key=XXXXX

The e-mail I received says: ERROR: You need to send a valid key to execute this file.

When using those cron jobs, they are not running:

> /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 'http://www.xxxx.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXXX&pass=XXXX&key=XXXXX'
>
> /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 "http://www.xxxxx.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXXX&pass=XXXX&key=XXXXX"

When working with php-cli:

> php /home2/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s xxxxx.org -u XXXX -p XXXXX -e Job -a execute

The PHP error log says:

> PHP Fatal error:  cli.php can only be run from command line. in /home2/xxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.class.php on line 91

When submitting the link directly in the browser, it works well.

**PHP 5.4.43
CiviCRM 4.6.7
Wordpress 4.4.1**

Comment: I also get the message 'ERROR: You need to send a valid user name and password to execute this file' but intermittently so I think it's a bug, and not going to help you with debugging your problems.  That message comes from the Civi code in System.php.  For what it's worth, here's my cron statement which does work:
wget -O - -q -t 1 "https://www.example.co.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=CronAd&pass=xxxxxx&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: Try submitting the link directly in a browser to see if it works, or takes an error.  You may learn more about the problem.

Comment: I have reported the spurious message (discussed above) - it's https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17954  I get these messages once/twice day with cron running perfectly!

Comment: I had similar problems. See http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11027/does-anyone-have-a-working-example-for-civimail-bulk-emails-on-wordpress-and-4-7/11059#11059

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for helping. Looking at the log showed that everything after & was getting truncated.

There should be "backslash" () sign before "and" (&) sign.

> /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1
>   http://www.site.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=XXXX\&pass=XXXX\&key=XXXXX

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try creating a wgetrc file that contains all your values.  Check the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) for wget as a reference.. Here's a wgetrc of mine:

```
post-data=name=civicron&pass=<password>&key=<sitekey>
output_document = -
quiet=on
timeout=1
```

Also - check your Apache/nginx logs for the actual URL that was requested that corresponds to a wget that resulted in a "You need to send a valid key" error.  Maybe something is getting truncated; the web server log can help determine this.