# Running cron job CiviCRM on Drupal in the CPanel

Tags: cron-job

I am trying to configure the CiviCRM file "sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php" to be run as a cron job.  If I paste the url:

https:// domain.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=**username**&pass=**password**&key=**key**

in to the web browser, with the username, password and key specified then the cron.php is triggered.

But if I create a cron entry via the CPanel and define the command as:

**/usr/local/bin/php** /home/username/domain/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=**username**&pass=**password**&key=**key**

then the cron job is not triggered.

If i try:

**/usr/bin/wget** https://domain/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=**username**&pass=**password**&key=**key**

then the cron job is equally not triggered.

Any ideas what the issue might be?  Or what else i could try to get it to run?

At the moment I do not have access to server logs so can't see what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I appear to have resolved the issue with the help of the thread at [Cron job with shared hosting CPanel](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9130/cron-job-with-shared-hosting-cpanel?rq=1)

The issue was related to missing backslashes after the username and the password.

/usr/bin/wget https://domain/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=username\&pass=password\&key=key